# Why does flock removes existing text from a file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, flock

So, I am trying to get an exclusive lock on a text file using Flock and a line of text to that file however while doing so it removes whatever text was there earlier.

```
( flock -n 200 || exit 1
echo "In critical section"
echo text >> file.txt
echo text added to file 
) 200>file.txt
echo "After critical section"
```

So if the file had let's say

```
123
214
242
232
```

and after running the script I am expecting something like

```
123
214
242
232
text
```

instead, all I get is

```
text
```

why would it behave like this, my guess is that it is replacing the original file but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- stdout (fd 1) is not redirected to (fd 200), `echo` commands are written to stdout.
- `200>file.txt` truncates the file.txt before commands in subshell are executed
- `echo text >> file.txt` appends `text`

using `>>` instead of `>` opens the file in append mode.

```
f() {
    (   flock -n 200 || exit 1
        echo "In critical section"
        echo text >> file.txt
        echo text added to file 
    ) 200>>file.txt
    echo "After critical section"
}

f & f & f & f ; wait
```

Note that the open (truncate/append) in outside of critical section.

Otherwise to block until lock is available don't use `-n`, compare

```
f_fail() {
    (
        sleep 1
        flock -n 200 || exit 1
        pid=$(bash -c 'ps -p "$(ps -p $$ -oppid=)" -oppid=')
        echo "$pid started"
        echo text >& 200
        echo "$pid done"
    ) 200>>file.txt
}

f_block() {
    (
        sleep 1
        flock 200 || exit 1
        pid=$(bash -c 'ps -p "$(ps -p $$ -oppid=)" -oppid=')
        echo "$pid started"
        echo text >& 200
        echo "$pid done"
    ) 200>>file.txt
}


f_fail  & f_fail  & f_fail  & f_fail  & wait
f_block & f_block & f_block & f_block & wait
```

Comment: Seems like it, will test it throughly before marking as correct answer.thanks for additional info!

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have

```
200>file.txt
```

on line 5. It overwrites the file.